# C++ sort vector<double> vs vector<Object> keyed on double member variable

Tags: c++, performance, sorting, vector

I have a vector of custom objects I'm sorting and noticed that the sort took a bit longer than expected.  I decided to look further into it and adapted the code from this [sort benchmark](http://solarianprogrammer.com/2012/10/24/cpp-11-sort-benchmark/) where instead of `vector<double>`, I'm sorting a `vector<Foo>`.  The result is that it takes about 2.5 times longer to sort the vector of custom objects, measured using `boost::chrono::steady_clock` as in the [original benchmark code](https://github.com/sol-prog/Sort_benchmark).  This doesn't really make sense to me since the key is the same and the memory is already allocated by the time sorting starts.  Why is that and does this affect other operations on such a vector, for example binary_search?

```
class Foo {
public:
  double _barKey;
  string _barStr1;
  string _barStr2;
  string _barStr3;
  int _barInt;

  Foo(double bk, string bs1, string bs2, string bs3);
};

  Foo::Foo(double bk, string bs1 = "", string bs2 = "", string bs3 = "") {
    _barKey = bk;
    _barStr1 = bs1;
    _barStr2 = bs2;
    _barStr3 = bs3;
    _barInt = 0;
}

struct less_than_key {
    inline bool operator() (const Foo& lhs, const Foo& rhs)
    {
        return (lhs._barKey < rhs._barKey);
    }
};

....

std::sort(std::begin(V), std::end(V), less_than_key());
```

Compiled using:

```
g++ -O2 -std=c++11 sort_object_bench.cpp -lboost_chrono -lboost_system -o gcc_test
```

Comment: Are you compiling with optimizations on?

Comment: how did you measure?

Comment: your `Foo` / `Peptide` constains some strings and an int on top of the double, so it isnt super surprising that rearranging the objects takes slightly more time than rearranging doubles and tbh I wont believe the factor of 2.5 unless you show how you measured it ;)

Comment: Copying a `Foo` object, with a number of `std::string` objects in it, is more expensive than copying a `double`. I am surprised that you are surprised by the results.

Comment: @RSahu They should be **moved**, not copied.

Comment: Btw, Your code contains syntax errors: the default arguments must be given in the declaration, not the definition (of `Foo::Foo()`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This doesn't really make sense to me since the key is the same and the
>   memory is already allocated by the time sorting starts.

The difference is not due to allocations taking place. The size of the vector doesnt change while sorting, so there are no allocations. However, `sort` has to copy the elements around to put them in the right place. And it shouldnt be too surprising that copying a double, 3 strings and an int takes more time than copying a single double.

Comment: I guess factor of 2.5 was more than I would've guessed.  So a binary search would not be affected then since nothing has to be copied?

Comment: @confusedCoder when it is about performance measuring is better than speculating. There might be a small overhead due to the aditional indirection. I wouldnt expect it to have any measurable difference, but dont believe anybody, just measure.

Comment: @confusedCoder you might want to repeat your measurement with a struct that has only a double member and nothing else. If you still get a 2.5 factor difference then you are doing something wrong on the measuring part ;)

Comment: Thanks, tobi303, great idea, I reduced the Foo object to only contain the double key and the overhead went down to about 3%.  This answers my question

Comment: @confusedCoder interesting, thats really more than I expected.

Comment: I've now played around a bit and adding just one string member to the object adds 44% in sort time.  2 strings goes up to 93%, 3 strings - 132%.  I really did not expect that kind of linear relationship.

Comment: @confusedCoder just consider what sort is actually doing: it compares your keys and it shuffles the elements. Comparing the keys is little more than a single instruction, so most of the time is spend for rearranging stuff

Comment: Actually, `std::sort` will **not copy but move** the objects around, which in this case (with three `std::string` members in `Foo`) makes a significant difference, if the strings are sufficiently large.

Comment: @Walter depends whether this is >= C++11 or not. And you are right for the strings, but for the `int` and `double` it wouldnt make a difference

Comment: @tobi303 This is C++11 as per OP. And for small strings it makes no difference.